# CSS/Sass Cascading Heading Styles with Unknown Top-Level Heading

Tags: html, css

**EDIT:**

[I made a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4dgx0wj6/2/) because it's not the easiest thing to describe.

**The challenge** is to achieve the same styles in the activity class *without* using JavaScript or changing the HTML in any way.

---

Problem: I'm working on a project with an emphasis on accessibility.  The constraint that this brings is that heading structure is incredibly important.  Unfortunately, we need to include repeating sections with their own headings that don't necessarily appear under the same heading level all the time.

For example:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<aside class="activity">
    <!-- Heading must be h2 as the activity falls under an h1 -->
    <h2>Section Title</h2>
    <p>some text</p>
</aside>
<p>some text</p>

<h2>Heading</h2>
<p>some text</p>

<aside class="activity">
    <!-- Heading must be h3 as the activity falls under an h2 -->
    <h3>Section Title</h3>
    <p>some text</p>
    <h4>Heading</h4>
    <p>some text</p>
    <h5>Heading</h5>
    <p>some text</p>
</aside>
```

My challenge is to make the headings visually appear the same based on their rank within the section itself.

I was wondering if I could achieve this using some CSS trickery, something along the lines of this:

```
// Level 1
.activity h2,
.activity h3,
.activity h4,
.activity h5,
.activity h6 {
    font-size: 18px;
}

// Level 2
.activity > h2 ~ h3,
.activity > h3 ~ h4,
.activity > h4 ~ h5,
.activity > h5 ~ h6 {
    font-size: 16px;
}

// Level 3
.activity h2:nth-of-type(1) ~ h3 ~ h4,
.activity h3:nth-of-type(1) ~ h4 ~ h5,
.activity h4:nth-of-type(1) ~ h5 ~ h6 {
    font-size: 14px;    
}
```

I'm still earning my stripes so I'm not entirely certain how to tackle this challenge.  Sass is available as an option, so I'd like to create a mixin as well, but I can probably handle that once I figure out an approach.

Any help is appreciated.

Note: I'm aware of HTML5 sectioning but we're opting not to use the new algorithm as accessibility support doesn't appear to be strong at this time.

Comment: Edit: Failing to understand - could you explain this more? "Unfortunately, we need to include repeating sections with their own headings that don't necessarily appear under the same heading level all the time."

Comment: Why are the headings unpredictable?

Comment: @TroyThompson it's not that the headings are unpredictable.  The sections will hold instructions, clarification, warnings, etc. and may occur anywhere within the main content.

Comment: I was wondering about this statement. "headings that don't necessarily appear under the same heading level all the time". Trying to understand why you can't have a normal system for handling sizes of your headings.

Comment: @TroyThompson - I don't know what a "normal system" would look like.  This is a WCAG 2.0 a11y project with static HTML pages rendered inside of iframes in an LMS. There's no server involved to assist with processing, so the more work I can offload into CSS, the less error prone (read: Humans) our system will be. These pages will be touched by "subject matter experts" (not trained for front-end design) which means they need to be extra robust and very user friendly. I can train them to use a logical heirarchy, but I can't rely on them to apply title-classes if that's your suggestion.

Comment: I spent some time trying to find an example of what you are describing, but I couldn't find anything. I did find an interesting quote - "Preset font sizes: Like colour palettes are, font sizes should be strict, predefined and intentional. From both a code and design point of view, you shouldn’t deviate from your scale—you shouldn’t really ever need to and doing so will just make code harder to work with." http://csswizardry.com/2012/02/pragmatic-practical-font-sizing-in-css/

Comment: Had a hard time understanding because to me, having relatively strict font sizes for headings is normal. That doesn't necessarily mean you shouldn't try though - I think you were on the right track with your CSS - to me it seems like trial and error - build up some HTML that represents many combinations or the worst possible scenario, and see if you can flesh out your styles to achieve what you are describing.

Comment: Lastly, I wanted to you explain more because it seemed like the problem was : "Users will be inputting content, so in order to have consistent styles, I want to make sure it doesn't really matter which heading they use in their content".  Its not too hard to have people use proper headings, is it?

Comment: I'm very much so looking for visual consistency.  Every one of these asides to the main content should have the same appearance, despite their heading levels starting at different ranks.  You can see this in the jsFiddle I added.  Both asides have a green, yellow, red order despite differing HTML heading ranks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73491/discussion-between-troy-thompson-and-mctaylor17).